# How to change Python version in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

so I want to make a project using python and have followed docs to install it but when I trying using it on vs code my version of python is 2 and not 3 even tho i've select my interpreter as python 3. I've check and python 3 is installed in my computer.

[image: version of python 3 installed in my terminal]
[image: version of python in my vs terminal]

Comment: In one case you start it with `python` and the other with `python3`. Therefore you get different interpreters. Python 2 is the default on macOS at the moment

Answer (score 0):

1) This is most probably because your environment variable paths include python 2. Add python3 environment variable to your paths if you haven done so.

2) In terminal, u can set your cmd line code to run with $python3 helloworld.py

3) https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Answer (score 0):

You should be using virtual environments whenever you do something with Python (exception can be when writing single file scripts with no non-standard dependencies, and specifying the Python version with the shebang). That way, you'll completely isolate your environment.

The problem you're having now is that you rely on the path to your `python`. What happens if someone needs to run your project on his machine? And what he needs to install some dependency, but there's some conflict with the ones already install? Virtual environments help you with that isolating your environment and making it portable.

Here's a quick start, which will help you to understand it:

```sh
❯❯❯ which python
/usr/bin/python

❯❯❯ python --version
Python 3.8.3

❯❯❯ python3.7 -m venv venv/

❯❯❯ source venv/bin/activate

venv ❯❯❯ which python
/tmp/python/venv/bin/python

venv ❯❯❯ python --version
Python 3.7.7

# Once you're done, you can deactivate the environment
venv ❯❯❯ deactivate

❯❯❯ which python
/usr/bin/python

❯❯❯ python --version
Python 3.8.3
```

This way, I've created a Python3.7 environment that is completely isolated from my system.

See [offical docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

EDIT: I've just seen that the title was changed to a VS specific question. You can still do it with the command line (and it's worth knowing how to do it and how it works), but [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) explains how to manage the virtual environments within the editor.

Comment: Thanks when check the python --version it still on Python 2.7.16

Comment: @AlistairTsang Have you created the virtual environment for `python3` and then activated it? After following the first four steps, you should be using Python3. The remaining steps are just to show how to deactivate and exit the environment.

Comment: so would I run my code within the virtual env? when i deactivate the environment and enter the --version it still gives me python 2.7.16

Comment: @AlistairTsang you should run the code while you are in the environment (i.e. after `source` and before `deactivate`). The `deactivate` example was just to see how to exist from the virtual env. Sorry if it was misleading