# Python version not changing in Vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I was creating a virtual environment in python 3.7.9 but vscode is creating an environment in python 3.9.12 (I have anaconda installed with that version). I used the command `ctrl+shift+p` to change the environment to 3.7.9 but it's created in 3.9.12. I had to uninstall anaconda to create an environment. How to fix this?

Comment: Did you research here on SO, e.g. for `change python version vscode` .. found [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62248330/how-to-change-python-version-in-vs-code) ?

Comment: I think it may be a problem when running the file. with the python extension. if you click the drop down on run there will be `run code` and `run python file`. choose run python file.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to change the Python version in VS Code:

1. change to your project path (e.g. using `cd`)
2. create a new virtual environment (`venv`) using your Python binary in the given version (e.g. `python3.7`)：

   ```sh
    `which python3.7` -m venv .venv
   ```
3. change your VS Code interpreter by clicking in the status-bar (see red rectangle below)
   [image: the changing button]

Answer (score 0):

There is a corresponding relationship between Python version and CONDA version.

A simple modification of interpreter cannot change the python version. You must install the CONDA environment of the corresponding version of Python.

Here is the [download page](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/) of conda